# What does Ruby return automatically for "while" and "for" statements?

Tags: ruby

I am working on my own dialect of Coffeescript with a Ruby-flavored syntax.

My compiler implements the automatic `return` feature from Ruby for methods and lambdas. In Ruby, if the last expression of a method, lambda or Proc is an `if`, then something inside the `if` block is returned or nil is returned.

I cannot seem to figure out what is returned in the case of a `while` or `for` loop because if I return a value from inside the loop I prematurely exit the loop. So, can anyone please tell me what is actually returned and how Ruby determines what it needs to return in the cases of `while` or `for`?

I looked at the Coffeescript output and it is always returning a `_result` array if the last expression is a `while` or `for`. But we don't always produce arrays using `while` and `for` statements. So, I am very confused.

Comment: If you've not seen it, you might be interested Pat Shaughnessy's book, "Ruby Under a Microscope", which came out a couple of months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems easy enough to test, no?

```
>> r = while i < 6
>>       i = i + 1
>>     end
=> nil
>> r
=> nil
```